Rotation matrices and change of basis

brekely physics book chapter 2 page 30 , a question about rotating a system by $ \frac{\pi}{2} $ around the z axis clockwise direction and writing vectors according to the new axis after rotation

while solving the question above I stumbled upon something that confused me
i was trying to make the vector invariant under change since I want to describe it in accordance to the new axis  but I made a matrix that transforms the vector itself in the older coordinates system after a lot of confusion I wrote a matrix that inverses the axis not the vector itself and I noticed when applying it to the vector I get its components according to the new basis while the matrix transpose applied to the same vector gave me the vector transformation in the same space
in order to understand why we the get components,  I wrote a set of equations for each new axis and component. By substituting the old components with the new ones in these equations and ensuring equality, I arrived  at the conclusion that both sides yield the same components. and when making a transformation matrix from there I got the same one as above so I am convinced of what it does but still do not fully understand
$$  \left[
 \begin {array}{cc}  x' \\\ y' \\\ z'  \end{array}\right]=
 \left[  \begin {array}{cc} 
            0  & 1 &0   \\\ 
           -1  &0 &0 &
\\\ 0&0&1\end {array}
 \right]  \left[ \begin {array}{cc}  x\\\ y \\\ z  \end{array}\right]
$$
if the concepts of  when am I rotating the vector itself and  am I rotating the axis can be explained between changing the basis while not the vector and when changing the vector itself

The end result will be quite obvious, but I am showing
a lot of things that apply to general coordinate transformations.
For the two bases write
\begin{align}
e_1&=\pmatrix{1\\0\\0}\,,&e_2&=\pmatrix{0\\1\\0}\,,&e_3&=\pmatrix{0\\0\\1}\,,\\[4mm]
e'_1&=\pmatrix{0\\-1\\0}\,,&e'_2&=\pmatrix{1\\0\\0}\,,&e'_3&=\pmatrix{0\\0\\1}\,.
\end{align}
One and the same vector $\boldsymbol{v}$ can be written in two ways:
$$\tag{1}
\boldsymbol{v}=v_1\,e_1+v_2\,e_2+v_3\,e_3= v'_1\,e'_1+v'_2\,e'_2+v'_3\,e'_3\,.
$$
These expansions in bases obey the same bilinearity rules as scalar products do,
despite the fact that $e_i,e'_i$ are vectors.
Since
\begin{align}\tag{2}
e'_1&=-e_2\,,&e'_2&=e_1\,,&e'_3&=e_3
\end{align}
we can view the covariant relationship between the bases as
$$\tag{3}
\pmatrix{e'_1\\e'_2\\e'_3}=\pmatrix{0&-1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&1}\pmatrix{e_1\\e_2\\e_2}
$$
(this is not a matrix/vector multiplication, but again it follows the same rules).
Writing $R$ for the rotation matrix in (3) and formally (1) as
$$
\boldsymbol{v}=\langle v,e\rangle=\langle v',e'\rangle
$$
we have obviously
$$
\boldsymbol{v}=\langle v',R\,e\rangle=\langle R^\top v',e\rangle\,.
$$
Since the coefficients $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ in a basis expansion are
unique  it follows that
$$
v=R^\top\,v'\,,
$$
must hold. This can be
written differently, as $v'^\top R=v^\top $ or as $v'^\top =v^\top R^\top\,:$
$$\tag{4}
\pmatrix{v'_1,v'_2,v'_3}=\pmatrix{v_1,v_2,v_3}\pmatrix{0&1&0\\-1&0&0\\0&0&1}
$$
which is the contravariant relationship between the covectors (row vectors) $v^\top$ and $v'^\top\,.$
Sanity Check: We have shown
$$\tag{5}
v'_1=-v_2\,,\quad v'_2=v_1\,,\quad v'_3=v_3\,.
$$
Plugging this and (2) into (1) shows that it is correct. This could have been
guessed easily from (1) and (2).
Active and Passive Transformations:

The contravariant relation (4) comes from a coordinate transformation
where the vector $\boldsymbol{v}$ does not change. It is thus
a passive transformation.

In contrast, when we rotate a vector $\boldsymbol{v}$ by $R$ (clockwise around the $z$-axis by $\frac\pi2$) we have an active transformation. Keeping the convention that
components are covectors (row vectors) this gives
$$\tag{6}
\pmatrix{w_1,w_2,w_3}=\pmatrix{v_1,v_2,v_3}\pmatrix{0&-1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&1}\,.
$$
Being covariant this differs crucially from the contravariant (4).  Also note that the active transformation maps $\boldsymbol{v}$ to
$$
\boldsymbol{w}=w_1\,e_1+w_2\,e_2+w_3\,e_3
$$
where the basis vectors $e_i$ have not changed.



first and for most thank you this was organised so well that it made the connection crystal  clear ,would you mind also going into rotating  the vector itself vs just rotating the axis

This should be addressed in the edit.

This question will sooner or later be asked again (duplicate). But with no upvotes and/or being accepted by OP the answer cannot be used to close the duplicate. Please help the community by accepting it.

thank you , would have loved to upvote your answer but not enough reputation for that yet , could not ask for a better explanation
